# Colorbox not adding the width and height of the border images to the image dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm having size issues with the jQuery colorbox plugin. When I click an image to display it in the colorbox it grabs the correct size from the image to display but it fails to add the width and height of its own borders (the ones of the pop-up box) which are 25px each. The inner width and height are correct while the outer width and height end up having 50px too little. This causes the image to not be displayed at all. Only the borders are visible and not in the correct location.

I have searched for hours trying to find someone with a similar problem and have tried many things to get it fixed, but still I have no clue why it keeps doing this.

Some info:

- I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 (this cannot be changed and I'm pretty sure that it's compatible)

- My current code looks like this

```
$.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#inline_content'});
```

Where #inline_content is the ID a HTML image tag

- The files are loaded in this order:  colorbox CSS - jQuery - colorbox JS

- Firebug does not show any javascript errors

EDIT:
I figured out that somebody else changed the version of colorbox to the newest one. Which only works with jQuery 1.4.3+
This was causing the strange issue.

Thank you for you help and sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

No one could help you with such description. I create test jsfiddle for you:

- http://jsfiddle.net/QkdL2/

Edit this example and press `Update`, then show us link with problem demonstration (also include your css styles).

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far, but this is also part of the problem. In an environment with only the scripts needed for colorbox it works perfectly. I have to place this into an existing website that includes a lot of scripts and CSS that I cannot control. I did not expect a direct answer like "do this and it's fixed" but maybe somebody can tell me where I should be looking to find the error. I do no think I can recreate the issue in your jsfiddle. I cannot link the website because it is an internal URL. Do you have any idea how other scripts could cause problems?

Comment: @gen try to compare css styles of rendered elements, open firebug and on style tab find difference, maybe you have conflicts?

Comment: I found the problem. Your reply made me recheck the scripts aswell. (I edited the original post) Thank you!